# AOP Session scoped proxy gets singleton scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am trying to inject a session scoped inputForm bean into Singleton scoped controller but the InputForm bean gets singleton scope instead. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class MyAppController {

// AOP session scoped proxy type CGLIB
@Autowired  private InputForm inputForm;

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView returnHome() {
    Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    modelMap.put("inputForm", inputForm);
    return new ModelAndView("homePage", modelMap); 
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processData(@ModelAttribute("inputFormAttr")                                                    
     InputForm inputFormBinding) {
// inputFormBinding is the data bound from inputs in jsp page.
this.inputForm = inputFormBinding;
}


<bean id="inputForm" class="<package>.InputForm" 
                    scope="session" init-method="init">
    <property name="id" value="${property_id}"/>
    <property name="name" value="${property_name}"/>
    <property name="phoneNo" value="${property_phone}"/>
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: How can you tell it's singleton?

Comment: How are you loading the `Controller` class?

Comment: `<context:annotation-config />` @Sotirios: Default scope is singleton right?

Comment: Yes, the default is singleton. But you haven't used the default scope. You've used `session`.

Comment: Sorry I meant controller is in singleton not the bean that is injected

Comment: Please post your `InputForm`. My guess is that you have a `@Component` or related annotation on the class. But I wonder why do you need a session scopes object instead of an object that is stored in the session with `@SessionAttributes`. Do you really need it to be a session scoped proxies object? Do you use it else where in your application?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine. Spring will inject a proxy into the injection target

```
@Autowired  private InputForm inputForm;
```

But when you invoke methods on this object, the proxy will delegate to an object that will be stored in the `HttpSession`.

Note that each of the target beans will have the same properties set through your property placeholders

```
<property name="id" value="${property_id}"/>
```

Those might mislead you in your debugging, but the bean does have session scope.

Comment: But then how can I get the properties in session scope?

Comment: @User49234123412341 You're setting the properties of all objects created from that bean definition to the same value. If you change one in one session, it will not affect another in another session.

Comment: But that's my problem. I opened up the app in different machine and they see the same properties in inputForm as first machine. As you can see the get request just gets proxy and sets into model map

Comment: @User49234123412341 Did you change the properties' values in either of the machines?

Comment: Whatever is changed in first machine by other controller post request is seen by second machine when the get request is invoked

Comment: @User49234123412341 Please edit your question and add what you change.

Comment: @User49234123412341 Well there's your problem. You aren't modifying the object, you're modifying the reference: `this.inputForm = inputFormBinding;` You're assigning some object reference to an instance variable. Of course all sessions will see the same object. The whole point is that Spring injects its own proxy object for that instance variable and that proxy manages the session-scoped objects.

Comment: Damn, my bad... I got your point, Thanks :) Anyway, I am planning to solve the problem by using session scope for my Controller, do you think it's a good idea.

Comment: @User49234123412341 No, I don't think that is a good idea (but I barely know what you are trying to do). I would keep the controllers as singletons without state as much as possible. If you described what you want, it may be easier to explain.

Comment: @User49234123412341 What **is** the problem?

Comment: @User49234123412341 It already is session scope. What you could probably to do inside `processData` is `this.inputForm.setSomeProperty(inputFormBinding.getSomeProperty())`. Or use `@SessionAttributes`.

Comment: `this.inputForm` always gives me the object with singleton instance fields. I am using @SessionAttributes to solve the problem. Thank you so much.